# Java-matrix exponentiation to find the Fibonacci sequence

Tags: java, matrix, fibonacci, exponentiation

wondering how to map this to code as thats all i have to go off of
http://puu.sh/fKuyF/815515d66f.png

Comment: Wite down a smaple Fibonacci sequence and try to figure an algo to create that sequence

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth here are a couple of Fibonacci examples in Java.

```
public class Fibonacci
{
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            System.out.print(fib1(i));
            System.out.print(' ');
        }
        System.out.println();
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            System.out.print(fib2(i));
            System.out.print(' ');
        }
    }

    // naive recursive implementation
    static int fib1(int n) {
        if (n < 2) return n;
        return fib1(n - 1) + fib1(n - 2);
    }

    // dynamic programming implementation
    static int fib2(int n) {
        if (n < 2) return n;
        int n2 = 0, n1 = 1;
        for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
            int n0 = n1 + n2;
            n2 = n1;
            n1 = n0;
        }
        return n1;
    }
}
```

Not sure what matrix exponentiation has to do with it though.

Comment: Matrix exponentiation let's the algorithm get the run time of O(logn) I don't know how to code that matrix in the Lin, k though I understand how it works.

Answer (score 0):

There is so called Q matrix, one from picture

```
| 1 1 | n      | F(n+1) F(n)   |
| 1 0 |    =   | F(n)   F(n-1) |
```

Chain multiplication of Q will generate desired F(i). Multiply desired number of times, n-1, Q with self producing result `Qpow` and return `Qpow[0][0]`.

I posted squaring example on my blog, [take a look there for Java implementation](http://grumpyoldprogrammer.blogspot.com/2015/05/recursion-and-optimizations.html).

Comment: This is a little hard to understand. Can you rephrase to be clearer?

Comment: Q is that upstairs, we do matrix multiplication of Q and Q*Q = {{2,1},{1,1}} <--> {{F3,F2},{F2,F1}} we have F3=2